# How to describe that the plants or seedlings will grow well?

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Imagine seedlings which have great roots - the roots will help the plants grow well in your garden.

I can think of:

```
1. The seedlings will easily take new roots in your garden.
2. The seedlings will easily take root in your garden. 
3. The seedlings will easily take in your garden.
```

How would you describe it? Synonyms and single words are welcome.

Comment: All three are correct, but which one should be used is a matter of opinion (IMO). *To put down roots* is a synonym to *to take roots*, but this is very similar to your own solutions. Were you looking for something else entirely (and in what way would you like it to be different)? Are you looking for a single word perhaps (something like flourish)? Without more details it's difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Incidentally, once they take root and are doing well, you can say they are **thriving**.

Answer (score 2):

The usual phrase is not "take roots", but "take root", singular (it's an otherwise-archaic usage that's preserved). So:

> The seedlings will take root in your garden easily.

Or perhaps:

> The seedlings will easily take root in your garden.

This sounds a little better, but it's not a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

The seedlings are **vigorous**.  They will root **vigorously** in your garden.  With well developed roots like these, they will grow **vigorously** in your garden.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> The seedlings will **develop strong roots** in your garden easily.

Answer (score 1):

The seedlings will **readily** take **root** in your garden.

Drop the s from roots and rearrange the syntax.